# Patching Ingress Resource returns no change

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have 2 helm deployments (node-app-blue-helm-chart node-app-green-helm-chart ) and my ingress resource is seperate and like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: node-app-blue-helm-chart
          servicePort: 80
```

Tried to patch ingress resource with following command:

```
kubectl patch ingress ingress-resource --type=json \
  -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/rules/0/http/paths/0/backend/serviceName", "value":"node-app-green-helm-chart"}]'
```

Returns no change:

```
ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-resource patched (no change)
```

Describing resource:

```
$ kubectl describe ingress ingress-resource
Name:             ingress-resource
Namespace:        default
Address:          -----
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.72.0.6:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /   node-app-blue-helm-chart:80 (10.72.0.46:80)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false
Events:       <none>
```

What is missing?

Comment: Hi, do I understand correctly that you want to change the `serviceName`: `node-app-blue-helm-chart` **to**: `node-app-green-helm-chart`. I've used your example and it worked correctly for me (first time `ingress.extensions/ingress-resource patched` and running it one more time showed: `no change`). Could you please check if the resource changed by running: `$ kubectl describe ingress ingress-resource`?

Comment: Added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serviceName is not the recent representation. Changing it to service/name fixed problem.

```
$ kubectl patch ingress ingress-resource --type=json \
  -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/rules/0/http/paths/0/backend/service/name", "value":"node-app-green-helm-chart"}]'
ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-resource patched
```